# Unable to return primary key from sequence into Oracle Apex Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using a custom PL_SQL process to update an interactive grid.  The primary key was generated by a sequence and a trigger.   I have disabled the before insert trigger for now, and am pulling out the next value from the sequence in the APEX PL\SQL process and using it.

```
declare
    pNEW_ID number;

begin
    
    select DQ_RULE_CONFIG_SEQ.nextval INTO pNEW_ID FROM dual;

    if :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'D' then
        -- DELETE the record
        delete from T_DQ_RULE_CONFIG
        where ID = :ID;
         
    else
         
        if :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'U' then
            -- UPDATE the record
            
            update T_DQ_RULE_CONFIG
            set  
            dq005_sapphire_outcome = :DQ005_SAPPHIRE_OUTCOME,
            dq005_alias_term = :DQ005_ALIAS_TERM
            where ID = :ID;
         
        elsif :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'C' then
            -- CREATE (INSERT) as new record
           

                INSERT INTO t_dq_rule_config (
                    ID,
                    RULE_ID,
                    DQ005_SAPPHIRE_OUTCOME,
                    DQ005_ALIAS_TERM
                ) VALUES (
                    pNEW_ID,
                    81,
                    :DQ005_SAPPHIRE_OUTCOME,
                    :DQ005_ALIAS_TERM
                )
                returning ID into :ID;
                

           
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

Updates and deletions are working, but this isn't doing anything (the returning statement).

```
 INSERT INTO t_dq_rule_config (
                    ID,
                    RULE_ID,
                    DQ005_SAPPHIRE_OUTCOME,
                    DQ005_ALIAS_TERM
                ) VALUES (
                    pNEW_ID,
                    81,
                    :DQ005_SAPPHIRE_OUTCOME,
                    :DQ005_ALIAS_TERM
                )
                returning ID into :ID;
```

All Apex gives me is an error:

[image]

I have defined ID as the primary key column, it has no default value set.

How do I get the primary key to come back into the IG to get rid of this error?

Note:  I don't even need to use CUSTOM PL\SQL.  I can have the trigger generate the primary key, use an out of the box process to manage the saving of the IG, tick the "Return Primary Key(s) after Insert" on the IG process, and it all works - as long as I hide the ID column (type = Hidden).  If the column is part of the visible report, I get the error.  hiding it in the UI is not enough, I have to create it as type "HIDDEN"

Comment: Can you retry without the `returning id into :id` part? Also, please note that you are also "wasting" a sequence value on updates and deletes. Better to select the nextval only when you are sure to insert.

Comment: Doesn't work, same error.  In fact if I use the out of the box process and not my custom SQL, re-enable the trigger, and tick "return primary key(s) after insert" I get the same message

Comment: Then I think your grid has the Id as mandatory. Your form is not submitted because the client side validation fails.

Comment: It will be mandatory, it is ticked as the primary key column - but you would think the PLSQL process returning the value into the bind variable would work?

Comment: Did you try to turn the **Required** property **OFF** for the ID? Leave its "Primary key" property ON.